# Почему при переносе строки внутри блока с "width: fit-content", этот блок растягивается на всю ширину родителя?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Пример на codepen: https://codepen.io/Coder10000000000/pen/yLvwmdj

Почему блок .fit растягивается на всю ширину .container? Если ли способ сделать так, чтобы текст занимал всю доступную ширину (как при fit-content у родителя), но при переносе строки занимал ровно такую ширину, которая позволяет вместить текст без переполнения (как при ширине min-content)?

```css
.container {
  width: 350px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.fit {
  width: fit-content;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="fit">рентгеноэлектрокардиографическая фиброэзофагогастродуоденоскопия</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[width](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/width)

**fit-content**

Наибольшее из:

- внутренняя минимальная ширина
- меньшая из внутренней предпочтительной ширины и доступной ширины

В данном примере выбрана доступная ширина (ширина родителя), поскольку она больше внутренней ширины (слова перенесены), но меньше предпочтительной ширины (слова в одну строку)

Comment: Так проблема в том, что после переноса строки, контейнер растягивается на всю ширину родителя, несмотря на то, что сам текст визуально занимает на треть меньше места по ширине. Есть какой-то способ добиться поведения как указано в вопросе?

Comment: текстом сложно понять. можете картинку нарисовать, как должно быть?

Answer (score 0):

```
.container {
    width: 350px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.fit {
    width: min-content;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```